# Как качественно и быстро сравнить файлы?

Tags: java

Нужно вычислить из большого кол-во файлов дубликаты, пробуем через разные хеши (MD5, CRC32), около 20гб то это минут 10-20, нужен проверенный качественный но самое главное быстрый способ.

В программах по поиску дубликатов самое большое это 3 минут, но за 3 минут проверяет всю систему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Займитесь элементарной математикой. Файлы нужно читать с диска. А скорость чтения не быстрая. Далеко не самая быстрая, если это обычный hdd, то это 100-120МБит/секунду. То есть, в лучшем случае 15 Мегабайт в секунду. То есть, все файлы будут только читаться 23 минуты.  Даже если перейти на ssd, все равно будет медленно (в 3 минуты можно вложиться, но скорее всего уже упремся в процессор).

Что же делать? нужно взять более быстрый способ сравнивать файлы. К примеру, нет смысла считать хэш для файлов, у которых разный размер. Поэтому, вначале получаем полный список всех файлов и раскладываем их по размеру. Если размеры разные - файлы разные. Для них даже не считаем хэш. Если остались файлы с одинаковым размером, то считаем хеш для первого килобайта (мегабайта). Если он отличается - дальше нет смысла сравнивать. Если одинаковый - идем дальше, следующий мегабайт.

Comment: И сколько это примерно займёт времени ?

Comment: @TwerTrue  сравнить размеры, или даже хэш первого килобайта - практически мгновенно. Дольше всего займёи сравнение одинаковых файлов

Comment: Мы делаем аналог программы по поиску дубликатов, 10-20 секунд и мой диск с системой уже просканирован и я вижу результат, да это зависит и от языка (нативный он или нет) но хочется приблизиться в такому результату

Gemini если интересно (только под Mac)

Comment: Язык тут роли не играет - считывание жд одинаково медленно на любом языке

Comment: Может, 100-120 мегабайт в секунду?

Comment: @danpetruk но там же укладываются в 15-35 секунд чтобы проверить диск с системой (около 30 гб данных)